# How can I delete an node from a linked list with a single pointer?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

The book I study `#include` an exercise that asks us for modifying the following code which deletes a node from a linked list and building another function that does the exact thing with only one pointer:

```
struct node {
    int value;
    struct node * next;
};

struct node delete_from_list( struct node * list , int n){
struct node *cur, *prev;

for (cur = list, prev = NULL;
    cur != NULL && cur -> value != n;
    prev = cur, cur -> next)
;

if(cur == NULL)
    return list;
else if(prev == NULL)
    list = list -> next;
else
prev -> next = cur -> next;

free(cur);
return list;
}
```

Some code I've seen online is:

```
struct node *delete_from_list(struct node **list, int n) {
    struct node *entry = *list;
    while (entry) {
        if (entry->value == n) {
            *list = entry->next;
            free(entry);
            break;
        }
        list = &entry->next;
        entry = entry->next;
    }
    return *list;
}
```

But i have two objections for this:

1. This code contains two pointers actually `entry` and `list`.
2. We are `free()`ing the `entry` yet proceed to use it which "feels" like an error.

Please, if you are willing to help, either explain my objections or write a new code. Thanks.

Comment: I'd start with a piece of paper and a pencil and draw the situation.

Comment: ad.2: you are not using the entry once freed. There is a `break;`

Comment: Yes, i drew it but it is actually what made me question it. I drew `entry` pointing to a block of two boxes which means a `struct node` structure. And using `free(entry)` was just replacing the block of two boxes with a huge cross. It is right, isn't it?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Oh OK. That makes more sense right now. Thanks but isn't the code still has 2 pointers?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Its a nice little exercise. I know what you mean about the two pointers, but I think that the question setter is excluding the parameter. If the parameter is included then the original code has three: list, cur, prev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. This code contains two pointers actually `entry` and `list`.

You are required to build an algorithm that uses a single pointer. In your case, though it seems like two, `entry` is that **one** pointer which *the algorithm uses* apart from `list` which is actually an input to the *function containing the algorithm*.

> 2. We are `free()`ing the entry yet proceed to use it which "feels" like an error.

The code doesn't use `entry` after freeing it. Once freed, the loop breaks immediately due to the `break` statement succeeding the call to `free`.